# How to skip validation for ajax call?

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have an h:inputText, h:selectonemenu and commandbuton. Inputtext is mandatory field and I have defined it as immediate="true". Then I when I click the button I want to pass current value of selectonemenu to managed bean. But its passig null. How can I manage this validation so that it allows me to get the value of selectOneMenu in Managed bean..

My code is..

```
<h:inputText id="inputSome" required="true" requiredMessage="Pls enter something"/>
        <h:message for="inputSome"></h:message>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="recepients" value="#{controller.selected}" immediate="true">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{controller.tempNameList1}"></f:selectItems>


        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{controller.submit}"
            immediate="true"/>
```

Comment: It looks that you haven't bound the `<h:inputText>` value to your `controller` attribute (or maybe that's a typo.

Comment: As Luiggi Mendoza says, try binding your `h:inputText` to a property into your managed bean. Appart from that, it should take a value. Can you show us your backing bean code?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Its a example code. If I will bound my h:inputText the problem still remains. It will pass null value to controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put `immediate=true` in the commandButton, then `Invoke Application` phase is directly executed skipping the phases after (and including) validations. So "applying model values" phase is also skipped and the properties of managed bean are remained uninitialized. This causes you passing null for the value of `selectOneMenu`. The solution is, you have to retrieve the value for `selected` property of the controller **manually**, like bellow:

```
 Map<String, String> paramMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    for (String key : paramMap.keySet()) {
        if (key.contains("recepients")) {
            selected = Integer.parseInt(paramMap.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ans and also thanks for explaining the issue. :)